# Find all elements that appear more than n/k times

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of of size n and a number k, Find all elements that appear more than n/k times.

I believe this problem can be solved using the technique of moore's voting algorithm, by creating a map of size k which will store the number and their frequency.

Steps:

First create the map of size k and insert first k elements from array and update their corresponding frequencies.

for next k elements if the number exist in the map increase their count otherwise decrease the count of a existing number which has lowest count value (we can find this in constant time by keeping another map) If count ever drops to 0 delete that number of from map and add new number.

At the end check whether the numbers exist in map has frequency more than n/k or not.

**I look forward for your counter example or comment.**

eg: consider n = 10  and k=2

Consider the scenario

2,2,2,7,1,3,5,6,8,9

Map will have size 2.

For first element it will only contain 2 with count 3.
for 7 it will insert (since map has free blocks) and update it counts 1.
for 1 it is not in the map find the lowest count candidate in this case it is 7 decrease its count now count of 7 is 0 so update entry by inserting 1 and setting count 1.
This procedure will follow till the end of array at the end we have two candidates left in map 2 and 9 and their counts are 3 and 1.

We will check count of both element and return result which has count > n/k. (we don't need to loop through array k times we can store the count initially in some other map) so checking the counts of candidate at the end we will perform O(k) operations.

Comment: What's the algorithm name ? and what do you specifically need, an implementation ?

Comment: I would like to know is my algorithms right ?

Comment: I think hashmap is the best data structure for this case. every time the number occurs, increment the value of the hashmap at the target number. After that, read the values and compare their occurence with n/k

Comment: could you provide an example to make your question and approach clear?

Comment: Before discussing the algorithm, I think the problem should be clarified. What type of elements are in the array? Are they positive integers between 1 and k? Or are they quite unconstrained - simply any type for which `==` is defined?  How can we create a map, if you don't specify that `==` (and a hash function?) are available for the element type?

Comment: Even better: your question shouldn't discuss your algorithm at all. You should create your own 'Answer' and discuss your algorithm there. This is the normal way on StackOverflow. In fact, I might do that myself for you shortly, if nobody objects?

Answer (score 2):

This does not work. Take a number `a` that appears `int(n/k + 1)` times at the start of the array, followed by some random mix of `n-int(n/k+1)` numbers not containing `a` anymore. Since `n-int(n/k+1)` for `k>2` is larger than `int(n/k+1)`, there is no guarantee that the array entry for `a` won't drop to zero.

An improved version of this algorithm, which doesn't produce false negatives (but can produce false positives) is in [Data Streams: Algorithms and Applications
 By S. Muthukrishnan](http://books.google.com/books?id=415loiMd_c0C&lpg=PA33&ots=Jx2avzHlNk&dq=%22frequent%20elements%2Fheavy%20hitters%20sampling%22&pg=PA34#v=onepage&q=%22frequent%20elements/heavy%20hitters%20sampling%22&f=false), section 5.1.2, "Frequent elements/heavy hitters sampling".

Comment: Thanks @Rafal I changed my algorithm a bit if the number exist in the map increase their count otherwise decrease the count of **any** existing number in map.   TO  if the number exist in the map increase their count **otherwise decrease the count of a existing number which has lowest count value (we can find this in constant time by keeping another map)** in map.